# Check for google play service returns invalid suddenely

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm developing a location aware Android application and it has been working fine until today. After doing some modifications and trying to re-run the app in my device, it suddenly returns SERVICE_INVALID (error code 9) when checking for Google play service.

```
private boolean isGooglePlay(){
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if(status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        ((Dialog) GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 10)).show();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: use latest google-play-services library may be this will solved your problem

Comment: doesn't solve the problem :/

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest google-play-service library require you to use a real device or an emulator image from Google API instead of the x86 
Google APIs (Google Inc.) API Level 19
instead of 
Android 4.4 - API Level 19
You can find the explanation on the [developer](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) website

```
To test your app when using the Google Play services SDK, you must use either:

A compatible Android device that runs Android 2.3 or higher and includes Google Play Store.
The Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.
```

I was having the same error before switching my image to Google APIs and it fixed it.